# Translate: My Jesus, I love You above all things”

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, ecclesiastical-latin

How would this sentence be translated to Latin? Mostly I need help properly piecing it together from common Latin phrases. So far I have:

Mi Iesu, amo te omnia.